# Windows 10 storage pool and hard drive recovery

Tags: storage

OS Win 1 
I am looking for any suggestions as I have spent nearly 20+ hours working with MS and reading through blogs and creating/deleting storage pools to simulate scenarios.

Basically I had storage pool that had a "Retired" drive and when working with Microsoft they asked me to use a USB drive and attach to existing storage pool to remove the other.

Adding the USB Drive (2 TB w/ 1.5 existing backup data) sorta worked but ended up having to remove the storage pool and recreate.

However the old pool still shows my old drives + the one "OK" good USB Drive that is part of the pool. But the Storage pool is "Red" and has an error of Inaccessible; check the physical drives section and only allows me to delete the pool.

I do NOT want to delete in fear (and tested) that it will remove my USB backup drive from the storage but also make my data inaccessible (data on the drive prior to being part of the pool. 2-way mirror

I purchased data recovery software and scanned the drives and see some of the data but the name/file structure seems a little off and my preference would be to be able to access my original files on the USB (Videos and pictures mainly) and delete the useless storage pool.

Does anyone know how to access data prior to being part of a storage pool or find a safe way to remove/delete a pool?